# Redirect root (and only root) URL to another domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I'm looking to redirect my domain example.com and www.example.com to http://example2.com, but I want to keep all visits to my posts at http://example.com/sdfhs to continue through to their destinations.

Essentially, I ONLY want to redirect the root and www domain and leave the rest untouched.

How can I do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if you still have this issue, but I have had it on one of my domains (Yourls installation).  Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It works on my installation, but check it out on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply match any URL with at least 1 character `(.+)` and mark that as the last rule for the rewrite engine to look at `[L]`.
Then afterwards redirect anything else `(.*)` to the new domain (the only other thing that wouldn't be matched up to that point would be the root).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This would redirect all domains to example.com. I don't believe that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} example\.com|www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example2.com [L]
```

Comment: This would redirect all domains to example.com. I don't believe that is desired.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary sorry, you are right, I had in mind this only applies in his (virtual) host. I have updated with a test for http_host, i hope my re pattern is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example2.com [L,R=301]
```